# How to configure a MS display adapter v2 with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, wireless-adapter

I recently purchased a MS display adapter v2 for my laptop running Windows 10.  I find that each time I use the adapter I must first "remove" it from bluetooth and then "add" it again. This is really a pain.  It shows on my list of blue tooth devices as not connected. There seems to be no way to connect it without first removing it and adding it again. Also in the dropdown under the blue tooth icon the "allow a device to connect" is grayed out.  I've replaced the device drivers for blue tooth and the adapter but it didn't help.
Has anyone had this problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE.....  I had to install the MANUFACTURERS Bluetooth and WiFi drivers.  The Athros driver worked fine on my Acer Windows 10 but the Intel did not work as well. The driver that is installed with Windows Update is a generic driver which works but may not provide all functionality that you need.
I also went to MS Store and downloaded and installed the updated driver for the V2 display adapter.    PROBLEM SOLVED!!

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution to my problem t this link.
https://www.bemidjistate.edu/offices/its/knowledge-base/connecting-to-a-wireless-display-with-windows-10/

Problem Solved

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.